# GPRS+GPS communication

Tags: gps, serial-port, communication, gprs

My project is using GPRS and GPS shield. My board has 2 UART ports so there will be no problem when I use the 2 shields. My codes for both shields works fine alone, but when I already integrated the two in one board, the code for the GPS doesnt continue (GPRS works), its like stuck in this command

```
ptr = strstr(GPS_data, "$GPGGA"); //search GPGGA String
```

but this command runs perfectly if I only use the GPS shield alone with the board. Im using 2 baud rates, 57600 for GPRS and 9600 for the GPS. What could possibly be the problem for this? Thank you!

This is a part of my GPS code.

```
void SEND_data()
{
  digitalWrite(gpsPin, HIGH);

  Serial1.begin(9600); //GPS shield communication
  pinMode(TX1, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(TX1, HIGH);

  Serial1.write(Serial1.read()); 
  while(!ptr)
  {
    while(Serial1.available())
    delay(10);
    {
      GPS_data[i]=Serial1.read(); //output of the GPS
      i++;
      j=0;
      delay(10);
    }
    ptr = strstr(GPS_data,"$GPGGA"); //search GPGGA String
    digitalWrite(gogoPin, HIGH);
  }
   digitalWrite(sendPin, HIGH);
```

My problem is that `digitalWrite(sendPin, HIGH)` above doesnt light anymore, so basically the running code stops in the part of the `digitalWrite(gogoPin, HIGH);` just above the bracket ({).

Comment: Pleae provide brand/model info for board you are using and GPS/GPRS shields.

Comment: Im using this arduino compatible board, Gizduino+ and a memory of 64K. http://www.e-gizmo.com/KIT/gizduino+%20164,324,644.html.

Comment: @thePhoenix18 and what about GPS and GPRS shields?

Comment: Im still using the shields of E-gizmo's. GPS - http://www.e-gizmo.com/KIT/gps%20shield.html, GPRS - http://www.e-gizmo.com/KIT/gsm%20shield.html.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be in fact a shield stacking problem. If you have bought your shields from same place as your Arduino board this is the case.

Seesntially, you have connected 2 devices to TX/RX pins which is **not** supported. Following post should explain it better [Arduino Uno RX TX Pins](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/77562/arduino-uno-rx-tx-pins).

Generally, in order to make it work, you have to rewire one of the shelds to use different pins and use [SoftwareSerial](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial) library to communicate with them. This also means you cannot use stacking capability unless physically modifying one of your shields.

On a side note, you might want to use [Electronics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) StackExchange site for futher questions regarding Arduino.

Comment: The board and the shields are just compatible, so I just stacked them up together.

Comment: Board + GPS is, Board + GPRS is but not nessesarily Board + GPS + GPRS

Comment: Is it necessary to use the SPI library when you want to communicate the 2 shields and the board?

Comment: @thePhonenix18 I'm not sure what are you asking now.